# Draw.io SQL plugin sets wrong primary key

Tags: sql, plugins, confluence, draw.io

I am generating two tables using the sql plugin in for draw.io inside confluence.

The following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
person_id int PRIMARY KEY,
country string,

);
CREATE TABLE countries (
country string PRIMARY KEY,
size int,
);
```

results in two tables where table "persons" has the country as the primary key (see screenshot).
Is it a bug? Is there a way to get rid of it?
Loading the tables 1 by 1 is not an option, since I am trying to import multiple tables.

Here is what I see in draw.io:

[image]

Comment: Same happening with my draw.io (version: diagrams.net 16.4.0). When I rename one of the columns than problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the primary Keys as follows?

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
person_id int,
country string,
PRIMARY KEY (person_id)

);
CREATE TABLE countries (
country string,
size int,
PRIMARY KEY (country)
);
```

Comment: the result is exactly the same

Comment: yes, it does not help a lot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).